# I can't login to my e-shop based on Prestashop 1.7. (No ps_employee table in DB.)

Tags: mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I can't find ps_employee table in the DB.

Is it possible that this table has just dissappeard?
How can I create new one and add new admin account?

Answer (score 0):

Of course is not possible this table can disappear by itself, anyway you can create it together with the associated `_shop` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ps_employee` (
  `id_employee` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `id_profile` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_lang` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lastname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `passwd` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `last_passwd_gen` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `stats_date_from` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `stats_date_to` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `stats_compare_from` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `stats_compare_to` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `stats_compare_option` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `preselect_date_range` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bo_color` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bo_theme` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bo_css` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `default_tab` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bo_width` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bo_menu` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `active` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `optin` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `id_last_order` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_last_customer_message` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_last_customer` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_connection_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `reset_password_token` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reset_password_validity` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_employee`),
  KEY `employee_login` (`email`,`passwd`),
  KEY `id_employee_passwd` (`id_employee`,`passwd`),
  KEY `id_profile` (`id_profile`)
) ENGINE=ENGINE_TYPE DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATION;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ps_employee_shop` (
  `id_employee` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_shop` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_employee`,`id_shop`),
  KEY `id_shop` (`id_shop`)
) ENGINE=ENGINE_TYPE DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATION;
```

Now only need add a record with your account details, in the `passwd` you can add whatever text, because you will need recover your password in the admin login page.